# Blender Eevee Vector Motion Blur?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, motion-blur, vector

So I am trying to use Eevee to render this animation, and I want to add motion blur. I like using the vector blurs in cycles but is there a way to use the nodes in Eevee?

I don't see a way to add a vector pass for eevee like in cycles [image]

[image]

Comment: Vector motion blur is a Cycles feature, that requires raytracing as far as I know, I'm not sure if it is possible for OpenGL based renders

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll hafta add in motion blur in my video editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of both renderers to get a mask. The Cycles scene would be super extra low fi to give you a fast render, and then you grab the Vector and the Depth from it and use it on the Composite screen to mix with your new Eevee render.

Here is one example of how to do it:

http://blenderboydiaries.blogspot.com/2019/01/how-to-get-motion-vector-blur-in_17.html

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.90 now supports Eevee motion blur, but is known to be unstable. It may take multiple attempts and messing around with settings to get a full render of your animation.

Comment: Problem with this, evee motion blur looks good but all passes are not motion blurred :( even in v3.0.1 )